# How to solve shape error in prediction part of LSTM model?

Tags: lstm, predict

I am attempting to add a prediction component to my LSTM model. The model takes a single input and produces a single output (same data), both representing temperature readings from a thermometer. I am utilizing the sequence-to-sequence data technique to divide the temperature data into three parts: training, validation, and test data. The problem arises when I try to incorporate the prediction aspect using the test data. The predictor initially starts making predictions but eventually encounters a shape error.
I am tuning the LSTM model to obtain the best possible results. Could you assist me in resolving the prediction issue and also guide me on adjusting the variables in prediction part in a way that minimizes the need for extensive modifications when altering variables such as test size, window size, and others in my modelare are changed.

```py
#### Link to Google Drive and load modules

# generic modules
import datetime, os
import itertools
import time
import pickle

# basic data science modules
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
import seaborn as sns

# keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam, SGD, RMSprop


# sklearn helper functions
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import  f1_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

# Import LSTM-related modules
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM

df = pd.read_csv('Master CSV v1.csv',index_col='Date/Time',parse_dates=True)

#df

# remove all rows with NaN values in DTS columns
df.dropna(axis=0,inplace=True)
#df.info()

# Convert 5-minute data to 48-hour data

# Resample the dataframe to 2-hour frequency and take the mean value within each 2-hour interval
df = df.resample('2H').mean()

df = pd.DataFrame(df, index=df.index)

df

X = df['warm well temperature (°C)'].to_numpy()

X.shape

test_size = 300
x_train_raw = X[:X.shape[0]-test_size]
x_test_raw = X[X.shape[0]-test_size:]

print(x_train_raw.shape)
print(x_test_raw.shape)

### sequence2sequence data set
window_size = 100 # Input window size
output_size = 10  # Output window size
shift = 5  # Shift for each iteration

def Sequence_splitter(data_raw, window_size, output_size, shift):
    # Initialize lists to store input-output pairs
    inputs = []
    outputs = []
    # Create input-output pairs
    for i in range(0, len(data_raw) - window_size - output_size + 1, shift):
        inputs.append(data_raw[i:i+window_size])
        outputs.append(data_raw[i+window_size:i+window_size+output_size])

    # Convert the lists to numpy arrays
    inputs = np.array(inputs)
    outputs = np.array(outputs)

    # Print the shapes of the input and output arrays
    print("Input shape:", inputs.shape)
    print("Output shape:", outputs.shape)
    
    return inputs, outputs

x_train, y_train = Sequence_splitter(x_train_raw, window_size, output_size, shift)
x_val, y_val = Sequence_splitter(x_test_raw, window_size, output_size, shift)

# Rescale input and output datasets
Sx = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
Sy = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))

x_train_scale = Sx.fit_transform(x_train)
# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]

x_train_scale = x_train_scale.reshape(x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1)
y_train_scale = Sy.fit_transform(y_train) 

x_test_scale = Sx.fit_transform(x_val)
x_test_scale = x_test_scale.reshape(x_val.shape[0], x_val.shape[1], 1)

y_test_scale = Sy.fit_transform(y_val) 

x_train_scale.shape

# function for LSTM model

def LSTMmodel(L, D, H, O):

    
    i = Input(shape=(L, D), name='input_layer')
    x = LSTM(H, activation='relu', name='recurrent_layer', return_sequences= False)(i)
    #x = LSTM(8, activation='relu', name='recurrent_layer2')(x)
    x = Dense(O, name='output_layer')(x)
    model = Model(i, x, name='LSTM')
    return model

# Create an instance of the LSTM model
lstm_model = LSTMmodel(L=window_size, D=1, H=4, O=output_size)



# Compile and train the LSTM model using the fit function
lstm_model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001))
r = lstm_model.fit(x_train_scale, y_train_scale, 
                   validation_split=0.2,
                   epochs=300, verbose=1, batch_size=128)

def plot_training_history(r, figsize=(10, 3)):
    f, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)

    # Loss
    axes.plot(r.history['loss'], label='Training Loss')
    axes.plot(r.history['val_loss'], label='Validation Loss')
    axes.set_title('Loss Trajectories')
    axes.set_xlabel('Epochs')
    axes.set_ylabel('Loss')
    axes.legend()

    # Adjust plot
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    return f, axes
# Call the modified function
plot_training_history(r, figsize=(10, 3))


test_predictions = []

first_eval_batch = x_train_scale[-window_size:]
current_batch = first_eval_batch.reshape((first_eval_batch.shape[0], first_eval_batch.shape[1], 1))

for i in range(len(x_test_scale)):

    # get prediction 1 time stamp ahead ([0] is for grabbing just the number instead of [array])
    current_pred = lstm_model.predict(current_batch)[0]

    # store prediction
    test_predictions.append(current_pred)

if i == 0:
    current_pred = current_pred.reshape((1, window_size, 1))
    current_batch = np.append(current_batch, current_pred, axis=0)
else:
    current_pred = current_pred.reshape((1, window_size, 1))
    current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:, 1:, :], current_pred, axis=0)
```

Comment: after 38 iteration error is:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-02706e097dba> in <cell line: 14>()
     16     current_batch = np.append(current_batch, current_pred, axis=0)
     17 else:
---> 18     current_pred = current_pred.reshape((1, window_size, 1))
     19     current_batch = np.append(current_batch[:, 1:, :], current_pred, axis=0)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 10 into shape (1,100,1)

Comment: What is the input shapes of your data to the fit() call? and would you give the summary of your model summary()